# What is an extended SQL schema?

Tags: sql, schema, object-relational-model

I have an assignment where one of the questions is asking for an "extended SQL schema" of a given object-relational database. Does anyone have an idea of what this question means?

The given database tables are: car_parts, engine_parts, tires and windows.

I have come up with the following code to create the schema (which I am a bit shaky about too):

```
CREATE SCHEMA products;
CREATE TABLE products.car_parts OF car_parts_type;
CREATE TABLE products.engine_parts OF engine_parts_type;
CREATE TABLE products.tires OF tires_type;
CREATE TABLE products.windows OF windows_type;
```

Is there anything else I need to add to this schema to create an extended schema? Is this the correct way to go about making a schema?

Answer (score 0):

I interpret "extended schema" to mean you have user-defined types involved - either custom table types or custom data types.